# Showing PHP variable in another page

Tags: php

I have a PHP code processing some data in index.php, and the result would be shown in a variable called "$output". Would it be possible to show the variable in another PHP page (i.e. result.php)? Many thanks for help.

index.php

```html
$output .= ''.$A.', '.$B.', '.$C.'';
```

result.php

```html
showing the data from $output
```

Comment: One word: PHP $_SESSION

Comment: make `$output` as a `global` variable to use.

Answer (score 1):

use session

**In your index.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["output"] =$output;
```

**In your result.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["output"]))
{
    echo $_SESSION["output"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very general, so it depends on your use case. But, for `result.php` to be able to access `$output` (or at least the data that it was originally assigned) you need to choose a way to persist that data. Here are some common ones:

- [Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) `result.php` inside `index.php` (not exactly persisting data, but loading the result page in the same request)
- Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php)
- Using predefined HTTP variables [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
- Save the ([serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)) data [to a file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- Use a database such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

The most simple for what I *think* you want is to use sessions.

Comment: Using get or post method

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of methods to do this.

I think that the most easy is use sessions.

> index.php

```
session_strat();
$_SESSION['output'] .= ''.$A.', '.$B.', '.$C.'';
```

> result.php

```
session_strat();
echo $_SESSION['output'];
```

Remember that you can get all the information of php in documentation, for example this in: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include`:

**index.php:**

```
$output .= ''.$A.', '.$B.', '.$C.'';
```

**result.php:**

```
include_once 'index.php';
echo $output; // whatever you need to do with $output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Many way you can show this
<?php
session_strat();
$_SESSION['OUTPUT'] = $A.','.$B.','.$C;

?>
result.php
<?php
session_strat();
echo $_SESSION['OUTPUT'];
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: `session_strat()` is not a function either